# Best .NET technology stack for building a Server Side rendered SEO Friendly Web App

Tags: c#, framework

I have worked in large non-SEO web apps that are built upon Angular and C# .NET REST API.
When it comes to SEO, Angular is not that great choice (Angular Universal has its own limitations).

I want to know what frameworks/tech stacks can be used to build a SEO Friendly website?
My basic requirements would be:

1. Server Side Rendering of HTML Pages
2. Occasional API calls to get a few details from the server without the need to refresh the page.
3. The backend programming language should be C#.
4. Possible separation of all the APIs from front-end so that the APIs could also be consumed by a Mobile App.